# BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher not returning Service data UUIDs

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing a UWP application, I am using the BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher method to capture advertising from BLE devices around. This all works fine and I can build a list of devices by capturing the BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs..... like below

```
private async void LockerAdv_Received(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs args)
{

    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () => 
    {
        ServiceUuidsFound += args.Advertisement.ServiceUuids.Count;

        Adverts.Add(args);
```

However, I want to capture the ServiceData UUIDs carried in the advertising data (in our case 0x180f for the battery service data and 0xb991 for our own service data).

If I capture the advertising and examine the Advertisement.ServiceUuids.Count as shown above the count is always zero even though I know there are two ServiceData UUIDs present and Apps like the Nordic nRF app finds them and displays them.

Also, if I use the debugger to stop execution and examine the Advertisement.ServiceUuids then they appear not to have been captured and are certainly not accessible as can be seen below:
[Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m75T3.png).

I have tried using

```
ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active;
```

and

```
ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Passive;
```

and it makes no difference.

Ultimately what I want is to be able to extract the ServiceData from the advertising data as it contains useful data for our application but if Windows won't even report the existence of the UUIDs then I am certain I can't get the data associated with it!!

So, what I need to know is it me doing something wrong? is it a limitation of Windows 10 (I am using the very latest version)? or is it perhaps an issue with the Dell Optiflex I am using?

Any help would be gratefully received

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing noting wrong. The debugger and watch just don't let you dig down deeper and show no native view.
Put the items you need in a list first and after that you can find out if the lists contain the items and even other collections with more items.
below is an example that shows you how. I think it does not cover all items, thats up to you:

```
    private async void OnAdvertisementReceivedAsync(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher,
                                               BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        //we have to stop the watcher to get the data from one advertising device only.           
        var device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(eventArgs.BluetoothAddress);
        if (device != null)
        /* Check all advertisement items for null!
         * Not all of them are present!
         * Null check is not done in this example!*/
        {
            var TimeStamp = eventArgs.Timestamp.DateTime;
            var LocalName = eventArgs.Advertisement.LocalName;
            var Name = device.Name;
            var BleAdress = eventArgs.BluetoothAddress;//ulong
            var Rssi = eventArgs.RawSignalStrengthInDBm.ToString();
            var ConnectionStatus = device.ConnectionStatus;
            var Access = device.DeviceAccessInformation.CurrentStatus;
            /* Shows advertising flags:
                  LimitedDiscoverableMode = 1,
                  GeneralDiscoverableMode = 2,
                  ClassicNotSupported = 4,
                  DualModeControllerCapable = 8,
                  DualModeHostCapable = 16.
             */
            var flags = eventArgs.Advertisement.Flags.ToString();
            var AdvNumberOfDataSections = eventArgs.Advertisement.DataSections.Count;
            /*AdvDataSections contains the advertisement data */
            List<BluetoothLEAdvertisementDataSection> AdvDataSections = new List<BluetoothLEAdvertisementDataSection>();
            foreach (var item in eventArgs.Advertisement.DataSections)
            {
                AdvDataSections.Add(item);
            }
            List<BluetoothLEManufacturerData> AdvManufacturerData = new List<BluetoothLEManufacturerData>();
            foreach (var item in eventArgs.Advertisement.ManufacturerData)
            {
                AdvManufacturerData.Add(item);
            }
            List<GattDeviceService> ServicesList = new List<GattDeviceService>();
            var services = await device.GetGattServicesAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
            if (services != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in services.Services)
                {
                    ServicesList.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
      /* Start the watcher again to get other devices or missing services or data */
    }
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for your help. I am glad it wasn't something I was doing wrong. I will try putting them in a list and then see what happens